# Why doesn't the cypher work for this query?

Tags: neo4j

Please see the graph. This model is supposed to be a product hierarchy. The root node is ProductTaxonomy, then with 'subcategory' relationship to link to subcategories, and all the leaf nodes are actual products.

Node Types from left to right are as follows:

```
Product: ProdTaxonomy
food: :Category:Food
smart phone: :Category:SmartPhone
iPhone: :Category:iPhone
Huawei: :Category:Huawei
iPhone X White: :iPhone:Product
iPhone X Black: :iPhone:Product
Huawei Mate 10: :Huawei:Product
Huawei Mate 9: :Huawei:Product
```

Two relationship:

```
subcategory
product
```

[image]

I want to find all 'smart phone' products, but this query returns nothing:

```
match (n:SmartPhone)-[*]->(p:Product) return p
```

Also, any comments on the way to model the hierarchy?

I want to ask questions like:

```
1) find all smartphone whose price < 800?
2) What types of smart phones are there?
3) What colors does iPhone have?
```

and other similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your graph, you'll notice relationships are going in the direction of the root, not toward leaves. Reverse the direction of your relationship and you should get the results you want.

Comment: That's absolute true! In addition, how do you like this modelling method of product?

Comment: use multi labeling. Label the products of Smartphones as the Subcategory. with that you can easily query on all smartphones with the properties.

Comment: @ShaikRizwana do you mean "create(:SmartPhone:Phone:Product, {name:"iPhone x While"})". If I don't this way, I don't have a way to connect different products under one root node in the graph. Each product will have its own subgraphs.

Comment: @user697911 yes that's how you can access the categories you want. Using Multiple labels will expand your search through all the levels. But make sure you specify the labels accordingly.